# Password Validation in a Form in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, validation, passwords

I'm creating a password function where the password must have a number, symbol and lower and upper case letters. However, nothing seems to be working when I try to input code to validate this. I have alerts working to let the user know if their password is less than 8 characters, if their confirmation password doesn't match the first password input and if they haven't put in a confirmation password. I'm hoping to keep it the same style.

I've got a piece of code in showing the lower case letter code that's not working. I've tried different pieces but literally nothing seems to work.

```js
window.onload = function() {

    var subButton = document.getElementById("submit");
   subButton.onclick = function value(passForm) {

   }

};



function value(passForm) {

    /** This function is being used to find out the values input by the user in both the password and confirm password text boxes.
     * The results are fed back to the user using alerts.
     * **/

   //confirm passwords match and have been created
    if ((passForm.passInput.value) == (passForm.confirmPassInput.value)) {
        alert("Your password has been created!");

    } else {

        var lower = /(?=.*[a-z])/;
        if (!lower(passForm.passInput.value)) {
            alert("Password must contain at least one lower case letter.");
            passForm.passInput.focus();
            return false;
        }
        else
        //Validating length
        if ((passForm.passInput.value).length < 8) {
            alert("Your password has less than 8 characters.");
            passForm.passInput.focus();
            return false;
        }

        else
        //Validating confirmation input
        if (passForm.confirmPassInput.value == "") {
            alert("Please confirm your password.");
            passForm.passInput.focus();
            return false;
        }
        else
        //Validationg confirmation matches
        if (passForm.confirmPassInput.value != passForm.passInput.value) {
            alert("Your confirmation password does not match.");
            passForm.passInput.focus();
            return false;
        }

        return true;

    }
    };
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/security.js"></script>
    <title>E-Commerce Security Features</title>
</head>
<body>
<heading>
    <h1>E-Commerce Security Practices</h1>
    <p id="heading"></p>
</heading>

<h3> Welcome to the E-Commerce Security Practices page! Here you will complete a few <i>simple</i> website security procedures and then decide
    what practice worked best and easiest for you. </br> Have fun!</h3>
<form name="passForm" method="post" onsubmit="return value (this)">
<p>In the section below, you are asked to create a username and a password in order to 'login'. </br> Your password <b>must</b> include 8 or more
characters, an upper and lower case letter and a number and a symbol. If your password does not include any of these requirements, it will not be accepted.</p>
Your Password: <input type="password" name="passInput" placeholder="Password" /> 
</br>
    Confirm Password: <input type="password" name="confirmPassInput" placeholder="Re-Enter Password"/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit" onclick="return value (passForm) ;"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's the output?

Comment: Please note that this is not an acceptable way to validate a password.

Comment: Your regex for lowercase search seems a bit overkill  `/[a-z]/`  maybe..

Comment: @weirdpanda the output is just the password confirmation message if its all uppercase

Comment: @AbbeyMoxen I added a solution below, please let me know if you need me to explain further. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If the passwords match, it will skip your entire else block:

```
 //confirm passwords match and have been created
    if ((passForm.passInput.value) == (passForm.confirmPassInput.value)) {
        alert("Your password has been created!");

    } else {
       //you are doing validation here.
```

You need to run multiple checks:

```js
window.onload = function() {

    var subButton = document.getElementById("submit");
   subButton.onclick = function value(passForm) {

   }

};



function value(passForm) {

    /** This function is being used to find out the values input by the user in both the password and confirm password text boxes.
     * The results are fed back to the user using alerts.
     * **/

   //check for lower case
        if (!passForm.passInput.value.match(/[a-z]/)) {
            alert("Password must contain at least one lower case letter.");
            passForm.passInput.focus();
            return false;
        }
        
        //Validating length
        if ((passForm.passInput.value).length < 8) {
            alert("Your password has less than 8 characters.");
            passForm.passInput.focus();
            return false;
        }
        
        //Validationg confirmation matches
        if (passForm.confirmPassInput.value != passForm.passInput.value) {
            alert("Your confirmation password does not match.");
            passForm.passInput.focus();
            return false;
        }
   
   //Validating confirmation input
        if (passForm.confirmPassInput.value == "") {
            alert("Please confirm your password.");
            passForm.passInput.focus();
            return false;
        }
   
   //check for upper ase
        if (!passForm.passInput.value.match(/[A-Z]/)) {
            alert("Password must contain at least one upper case letter.");
            passForm.passInput.focus();
            return false;
        }
        
           //check for number
        if (!passForm.passInput.value.match(/\d+/g)) {
            alert("Password must contain at least one number.");
            passForm.passInput.focus();
            return false;
        }
        
   
   //confirm passwords match and have been created
    if ((passForm.passInput.value) == (passForm.confirmPassInput.value)) {
        alert("Your password has been created!");
 return true;
    }
       

    };
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/security.js"></script>
    <title>E-Commerce Security Features</title>
</head>
<body>
<heading>
    <h1>E-Commerce Security Practices</h1>
    <p id="heading"></p>
</heading>

<h3> Welcome to the E-Commerce Security Practices page! Here you will complete a few <i>simple</i> website security procedures and then decide
    what practice worked best and easiest for you. </br> Have fun!</h3>
<form name="passForm" method="post" onsubmit="return value (this)">
<p>In the section below, you are asked to create a username and a password in order to 'login'. </br> Your password <b>must</b> include 8 or more
characters, an upper and lower case letter and a number and a symbol. If your password does not include any of these requirements, it will not be accepted.</p>
Your Password: <input type="password" name="passInput" placeholder="Password" /> 
</br>
    Confirm Password: <input type="password" name="confirmPassInput" placeholder="Re-Enter Password"/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit" onclick="return value (passForm) ;"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: sadly, this doesnt work. with just the password 'ollie123' I get no messages whatsoever not even a confirmation message. Thanks though!

Comment: @AbbeyMoxen hmm are you running the code snippet? I type in ollie123 and it prompts for an upper case.

Comment: yeah in the snippet it is working but for some reason when I put it in to web storm it doesnt accept anything

Comment: That would conclude the code is working but something about it within your environment is not. You should update your question to include all information please.

Comment: @AbbeyMoxen Are you including a javascript CDN in your local build? Is there any code missing that is not in the post?

Comment: no JavaScript CDN and absolutely no code missing as I created a new project and put all the code given to me in to it and it still didn't work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164585/discussion-between-josh-adams-and-abbey-moxen).

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to use regular expression look like

```
 (/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])[0-9a-zA-Z]{8,}$/)
```

Minimum eight characters, at least one letter, one number and one special character:

```
 "^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[$@$!%*#?&])[A-Za-z\d$@$!%*#?&]{8,}$""^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)[a-zA-Z\d]{8,}$"
```

Minimum eight characters, at least one uppercase letter, one lowercase letter, one number and one special character:

```
"^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[$@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d$@$!%*?&]{8,}"
```

Minimum eight and maximum 10 characters, at least one uppercase letter, one lowercase letter, one number and one special character:

```
"^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[$@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d$@$!%*?&]{8,10}"
```